# groupingBy and filter in one step

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I have a `Stream<String>`, and I want a `Map<Integer, String>`. Let's call my classifier function `getKey(String)` - it can be expensive. Sometimes it returns zero, which means that the String should be discarded and not included in the resulting map.

So, I can use this code:

```
Stream<String> stringStream;
Map<Integer, String> result = 
    stringStream.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(this::getKey, Collectors.joining());
result.remove(0);
```

This first adds the unwanted Strings to the Map keyed by zero, and then removes them. There may be a lot of them. Is there an elegant way to avoid adding them to the map in the first place?

I don't want to add a filter step before grouping, because that would mean executing the decision/classification code twice.

Comment: have you considered running `map` to change the stream from `Stream<String>` to a tuple stream and then calling groupBy and access by the temporary object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said that calling `getKey` is expensive, but you could still map the elements of the stream up-front before filtering them. The call to `getKey` will be only done once in this case.

```
Map<Integer, String> result =
    stringStream.map(s -> new SimpleEntry<>(this.getKey(s), s))
                .filter(e -> e.getKey() != 0)
                .collect(groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, joining())));
```

Note that there is no tuple classes in the standard API. You may roll your own one or use `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` as a substitute.

Alternatively, if you think the first version creates a lot of entries, you can use the collect method where you provide yourself the supplier, accumulator and combiner.

```
Map<Integer, String> result = stringStream
    .collect(HashMap::new, 
             (m, e) -> {
                 Integer key = this.getKey(e);
                 if(key != 0) {
                     m.merge(key, e, String::concat);
                 }
              }, 
              Map::putAll);
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use a stream of pairs like this:

```
stringStream.map(x -> new Pair(getKey(x), x))
            .filter(pair -> pair.left != 0) // or whatever predicate
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(pair -> pair.left,
                        Collectors.mapping(pair -> pair.right, Collectors.joining())));
```

This code assumes simple `Pair` class with two fields `left` and `right`.

Some third-party libraries like my [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) provide additional methods to remove the boilerplate:

```
StreamEx.of(stringStream)
        .mapToEntry(this::getKey, x -> x)
        .filterKeys(key -> key != 0) // or whatever
        .grouping(Collectors.joining());
```